# Why doesn't the TypeScript type guard narrow the type correctly when using intersection types?

Tags: typescript

The following code using TypeScript v1.8.10 type guards is giving me a compiler error, but I don't understand why it should fail:

```
export interface MyInterface {
    someFunction: () => void;
}

// ExtendedModelType is both a backbone model AND a MyInterface
export type ExtendedModelType = Backbone.Model & MyInterface;

class MyExtendedModelType extends Backbone.Model implements MyInterface {

    public someFunction(): void {
        let model: ExtendedModelType = new MyExtendedModelType();
        if (model instanceof MyExtendedModelType) {
            this.functionRequiringConcreteClass(model);
        }
    }

    private functionRequiringConcreteClass(param: MyExtendedModelType) { }
}
```

The compiler fails at line 13 with:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Model & MyInterface' is not assignable 
to parameter of type 'MyExtendedModelType'.
    Type 'MyInterface' is not assignable to type 'MyExtendedModelType'.
    Property 'functionRequiringConcreteClass' is missing in type 'MyInterface'.
```

The instanceof check should turn 'model' into a 'Backbone.Model AND MyInterface' because of the intersection type. But then passing 'model' to a function has the compiler complaining about the data structure.

Is this some edge case that I do know understand? Or is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Can you point to where `export type ExtendedModelType = Backbone.Model & MyInterface;` is a valid statement for what you are trying to do? That just looks like a binary and.

Comment: It is an intersection type. Search the Internet for "TypeScript Intersection Type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.5

> > Similarly, intersection types have the following assignability relationships:
> >
> > 1. An intersection type I is assignable to a type T if any type in I is assignable to T.
> > 2. A type T is assignable to an intersection type I if T is assignable to each type in I.

So according to 1, `model(I)` is not assignable to `MyExtendedModelType(T)` because none of the type in `model(I)` is assignable to `MyExtendedModelType(T)`

Following will work because `MyInterface` is now assignable to `MyExtendedModelType(T)` (dropping `private`)

```
export interface MyInterface {
   someFunction: () => void;
   functionRequiringConcreteClass: (param: MyExtendedModelType) => void;
}

// ExtendedModelType is both a backbone model AND a MyInterface
export type ExtendedModelType = Backbone.Model & MyInterface;

class MyExtendedModelType extends Backbone.Model implements MyInterface {

  public someFunction(): void {
    let model: ExtendedModelType = new MyExtendedModelType();
    if (model instanceof MyExtendedModelType) {
        this.functionRequiringConcreteClass(model);
    }
  }

  functionRequiringConcreteClass(param: MyExtendedModelType) { }
}
```